# calling event made by designer in SDK - c#

Tags: c#, events, kinect

So I have this code and I can not understand why it works like. Here is the code.

```
using Microsoft.Kinect;
```

,

```
KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
```

and

```
private void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    { ... }
```

first some info (for thous who don't know). The "KinectSensore" is an object. The "StatusChanged is called whenever a kinect changes status (it's an event handler).

What I don't exactly understand is how the whole second code works and what does the "e" get when it is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`StatusChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensorcollection.statuschanged.aspx) is raised by a `KinectSensorCollection` when the status changes, such as a Kinect being added or removed from that collection.  It is generally used to initialize a newly connected sensor, or to clean up when one is disconnected.  You can see it in action in many of the examples provided in the Toolkit.

[`StatusChangedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.statuschangedeventargs.aspx) only has [two members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.statuschangedeventargs_members.aspx):

- `Sensor`: Gets the sensor that has changed status.
- `Status`: Gets the status of the sensor, which indicates whether it is connected and ready.

You would use the `StatusChangedEventArgs` object to gain access to a newly added sensor (which you would know from the `Status` member) in order to initialize it.  On the flip side, you would use the same object to clean up event handlers and other objects associated with a specific `Sensor` when it is disconnected.

**UPDATE**

The `+=` operator in this case is adding an event handler to the `StatusChanged` event.  You can read about how `+=` is used to add event handlers in code at the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743596.aspx

This page mentioned `-=` in a code comment.  As `+=` adds the event handler, `-=` takes it away.

`sender` and `e` are arguments sent from event to the event handler.  You can search [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/) for all the details on them, and anything else related to C#.  `sender` is the object sending the event -- it will be a Kinect sensor.  `e` has two members, which I describe above.

Comment: Thanks for that but it's not what I wanted. I did know all of that already. I am new in C# and what I don't understand is more the basic syntax of C#. What does the += mean in the second code? I have seen them use -= also, what is that? Most importantly what does the value "sender" and "e" have after the event is called?